# How to pull the email address out of this string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Here are two possible email string scenarios:

```
email = "Joe Schmoe <joe@example.com>"
email = "joe@example.com"
```

I always *only* want `joe@example.com`.

So what would the regex or method be that would account for both scenarios?

Comment: Do you need only a subset of valid email addresses to be pulled out, or _all_ RFC-valid ones? Or, to put it another way, are you _only_ looking for _simple_ email addresses?

Comment: I'm not looking for valid email addresses, per se. I'm tying in to an API and those are the two formats I'll receive email addresses in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This passes your examples:

```
def find_email(string)
  string[/<([^>]*)>$/, 1] || string
end

find_email "Joe Schmoe <joe@example.com>" # => "joe@example.com"
find_email "joe@example.com"              # => "joe@example.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know your email is always going to be in the `< >` then you can do a sub string with those as the starting and ending indexes.

Answer (score 2):

If those are the only two formats, don't use a regex. Just use simple string parsing. IF you find a "`<>`" pair, then pull the email address out from between them, and if you don't find those characters, treat the whole string as the email address.

Regexes are great when you need them, but if you have very simple patterns, then the overhead of loading in and parsing down the regex and processing with it will be much higher than simple string manipulation. *Not* loading in extra libraries other than what is very core in a language will *almost always* be faster than going a different route.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to load an extra library, this has already been solved in the TMail gem:
http://lindsaar.net/2008/4/13/tip-5-cleaning-up-an-verifying-an-email-address-with-ruby-on-rails

```
TMail::Address.parse('Mikel A. <spam@lindsaar.net>').spec
=> "spam@lindsaar.net"
```

Comment: Not wanting to load a whole library just for this. Seems it could be done with some simple string parsing.

Comment: Here's the deal... if you are just parsing a limited and fairly consistent data set, yes, you could parse it.  OTOH, if you are parsing data that might come in from anywhere, you are going to have a *very* hard time getting it right - valid email addresses are very complex.